# \leftmark cannot be decapitalised(?)

Tags: mark

Apparently, a recently update doesn't allow `\leftmark` to be reformatted anymore:

```
\documentclass[10pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancypagestyle{stylemain} {%
      \fancyhf{}
      \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

% \pagestyle{stylemain}

  \chapter{chap 2}

  \newpage

  Lorem Ipsum Dolor blah blah blah
  \MakeLowercase{\leftmark}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled Result]

I've only noticed this behaviour just now after updating about 90+ packages, so I have no idea what caused this problem. Is there a way to print the same contents with being able to change upper- and lowercases?

Comment: The action of `\nouppercase` is to make `\MakeUppercase` into a no-op; you want to modify the definition of `\chaptermark` to remove `\MakeUppercase` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\nouppercase` command from fancyhdr worked by redefining some internal commands of `\MakeUppercase`. As the definition of `\MakeUppercase` has changed in LaTeX it now fails. `fancyhdr` would have to make `\text_uppercase:nn` a no-op locally too. But as egreg wrote in his command better would be to setup `\chaptermark` correctly from the start.

```
\documentclass[10pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancypagestyle{stylemain} {%
      \fancyhf{}
      \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    }
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\f@nch@reset
 {\MakeUppercase\relax}
 {\MakeUppercase\relax 
  \expandafter\let\csname text_uppercase:nn\endcsname\relax}
 {}{\fail}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{stylemain}

\chapter{ChaP 2}

\newpage

Lorem Ipsum Dolor blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding `\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}`: Imho this nesting never worked.

If you need that you should use the underlying commands from the L3 layer (eplx3):

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\text_lowercase:n {\text_uppercase:n{aBcD}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\MakeLowercase{\MakeUppercase{aBcD}}

\end{document}
```

[image]